# Trouble installing jQuery plugin in Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to include a jQuery plugin for a popup window in my website. I downloaded the fancybox plugin and included the following code in my `<head>`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="colorbox.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //Examples of how to assign the Colorbox event to elements
        $(".group1").colorbox({rel:'group1'});
    });
</script>
```

And the following code in the `<body>`:

```
<a class="group1" href="../content/myimage.jpg"><img src="../content/myimage.jpg" width="30px" height="50px"</a>
```

But the popup window is not appearing. I tried running this code alone in a single webpage and it runs perfectly, but it is not working on my Bootstrap website. Can anyone help please?

Comment: check location of colorbox.js and accordingly include it correctly.

Comment: You'd need to show us the code from your Bootstrap website and any error messages from the Javascript console.

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors? Made sure the links to the JS and CSS files are valid? etc...

Comment: The bootstrap.js requires jQuery.  Have you got jQuery in there twice possibly?

Comment: You're missing the closing > on your img tag!

Comment: i've included colorbox.js correctly.how do you check javascript console?

Comment: If you're programming Javascript you should really know how to check the console, or at least how to use Google to find out how to check the console.

Comment: yeah i checked it slhck ,thanks! and it says "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"!

Comment: It should also tell you where exactly (line number) the error occurs. You need to edit your question and give us a bit more info. Especially the code of your actual website, not the small code that is running anyway.

Comment: You've probably not linked the files correctly it would seem; secondly the word 'install' is pretty cringeworthy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap modal:

Include bootstrap jquery file and css file

1. bootstrap.min.css
2. bootstrap-theme.min.css
3. bootstrap.js
4. bootstrap.min.js

HTML:

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

         <a class="group1" href="../content/myimage.jpg"><img src="../content/myimage.jpg" width="30px" height="50px"/></a>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

SCRIPT:

```
$('#myModal').modal('show');
```

Use this [LINK](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) for reference